# How do I search for a list of Google map locations?

Tags: google-search, google-maps

How do I search for a Google map with tagged locations?

For example, how would I find a map of the locations of Tudor theatres in London, tagged on a modern London Google map? Searches for maps in Google result in (not surprisingly) a Google map with a long list of theaters, mostly current, and saved list.

Answer (score 3):

At November 2019, there is a way to browse Google Maps community lists in the Android app.

1. Search for the city or location.
2. Open the detailed view of the search result.
3. There is a **lists section**.
4. Expand the section and browse the list of lists.

Images:

1 & 2.

[image: Search the city]
[image: Result detailed view]

3 & 4.

[image: Lists section]
[image: List of lists]

Comment: Is that the only way? While this are "lists", they're not quite what I was looking for. They are all effectively promotional lists designed to direct traffic for businesses, and not the historical or informational kinds of lists I was interested in

Comment: Actually, these lists can be published by anyone, so if someone creates a public list of Tudor theatres, you should be able to find it here.

This is the only way I've found to browse lists, I too would be a huge fan of something more user-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, it doesn't seem like Google is promoting the feature.

As far as I can tell, there is currently no way to search for lists in an area on iOS Google Maps.

If you know a place that is on a list, you can search for that place, and if you scroll down, you will see the list it's on. But I tried clicking on one I knew, and it opened a URL which said 404 not found. I am wondering if lists have been phased out completely from iOS Google Maps but this was one accidental one that remained. You can share a list you made with a friend, though. The above way of browsing local lists by searching for a location (city, country) does not occur on iOS as well.

You also cannot google for them on a desktop computer. What does is appear is "Google My Maps" (https://support.google.com/mymaps/answer/3024396?hl=en&ref_topic=3188329), which appears to be a service for websites to embed maps with certain places on their webpages. They don't seem to be that helpful since they aren't labeled and seem relatively obscure.

The only way to get close to getting a list of local places seems to be to search for a city and to click on "Things to Do". There's also [www.google.com/travel](http://www.google.com/travel) where there are more filtered lists like "Loved by Locals", but it depends on the city what kind of filters or information are offered.

If you search for a specific restaurant and look at the reviews, you might see a "local guide". On iOS but not on desktop browser, you can click on their profile and choose to follow them, but this doesn't give you access to their lists, it only causes their reviews to show up higher whenever you click on a place. There is also no way to see a list of all the people you are following.

The only odd loophole/workaround would be to spend time searching local places, scrolling through the reviews until you see a local guide that looks promising, and click on their profile where you can see all their reviews in one place. There is a chance that if you like their taste, you will finally see a list of recommendations from someone you trust, provided that the local guide is writing most of their reviews in that area.

Google has made it very hard to have customised freedom with this service.

For further discussion, this seems like a good place to communicate with others: https://support.google.com/maps/community?hl=en

There are possibly other maps services with more freedom to create and share lists, such as OpenStreetMaps: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/63330/how-to-retrieve-only-restaurants-and-food-stores-in-an-area